# Не могу решить задачу на регулярное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Новичок в регулярных выражениях, более-менее лёгкие задачи получаются, эта вообще не выходит.
Задача - удалить из строки все повторяющиеся слова, оставив только одиночные (первые) слова (не меняя порядок слов).
Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import re
def remove_duplicate_words(s):
    pattern=r''
    return re.sub(pattern,'', s)
print(remove_duplicate_words("alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta"))
print(remove_duplicate_words("my cat is my cat fat"))
```

Comment: Не подходит задание для регулярки? Да я бы и через цикл решил, просто в задании регулярка тег стоит

Comment: @АлексейР чем? тут не о том, чтобы уникальные слова в строке оставить, а чтобы друг за другом следующие одинаковые убрать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `re` ничего не выйдет, так как чтобы оставить первые вхождения повторяющихся слов нужна поддержка блока предварительного просмотра назад неограниченной длины. Такая поддержка имеется в [PyPi `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```py
import regex

def remove_duplicate_words(s):
    pattern=r'\b(\w+)\b(?<=\b\1\b.*\1)\s*'
    return regex.sub(pattern,'', s)

print(remove_duplicate_words("alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta"))  # => alpha beta gamma delta 
print(remove_duplicate_words("my cat is my cat fat")) # => my cat is fat
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://tio.run/##jU1LCsIwEN3nFMFNmloKxZ1YvEigJHb6gebDZGrt6WvQblyIzuLNm@F9wkqDd6dtG23wSByhhwdjLXSJWn@Hpp3DNN40QbN4bGMW5ZnxNEETAboahTKZWo4yreulVkZVypS5qqSKuXhJEWhG984u42yy3VsIUfAoGQs4Osq@FB70FAbNDdAOvbb2E1uY0v9P3UHKH4V25enkY@Q76zQl17Y9AQ).

*Подробности*

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(\w+)` - Группа №1: одна и более букв, цифр или символов нижнего подчёркивания
- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?<=\b\1\b.*\1)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу перед текущей позицией имеется

  - `\b\1\b` - значение первой группы как целое слово
  - `.*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно больше
  - `\1`  - текст, захваченные первой группой (`\1` здесь необходим, так как блок находится после `\b(\w+)\b`)
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов.